# FPDF Header Question - Driving me crazy!

Tags: php, fpdf, while-loop, fpdi

I am trying to generate a PDF that outputs Item Names onto a template PDF (using FPDI) with the Username listed on the top of each page.  Every user can have a different number of items (i.e. if there are 1-4 items, only output one page; if there 5-8 items, output two pages, etc.)

Here is an example of what I am trying to do: http://www.mediafire.com/?k2ngmqm1jmm

This is what I have so far.  I am able to get all of the spacing to work by setting a TopMargin, but this doesn't allow me to put the Username header in.

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');      
require_once('config.php');  
require_once('connect.php');  

$username=$_GET['username'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_items WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

require_once('pdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('pdf/fpdi.php');

$pdf =& new FPDI(); 
$pdf->SetTopMargin(30);
$pdf->AddPage('L', 'Letter');
$pdf->setSourceFile('../pdf/files/chart_template.pdf');
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);

$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B');
$pdf->SetFontSize(7);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$pdf->Cell(20,5,$rows['itemname'],0,0,'C');
$pdf->Ln(45);
}

$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx);

$pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

Please help!

Comment: I'm confused and the link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it previously using the 'header' class extension:

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
function Header()
{
    //Select Arial bold 15
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
    //Move to the right
    $this->Cell(80);
    //Framed title
    $this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
    //Line break
    $this->Ln(20);
}
```

Have a look at the tutorial which explains the header usage at : http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm

Comment: I've tried adding the 'header' class in, but I still can't get it to work.  I think you need to call "$pdf = new PDF();" in order for the header to show up.  And this function doesn't seem to work with FPDI.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Michael - saved my life with "I think you need to call `new FPDF()`", cheers.  Not the solution to your problem, but may be the solution to the next person reading this.